# Intuit QuickBooks Integration (C#.NET/SDK) - Which PhysicalAddress property is for ZipCode, and State field?

Tags: c#, .net, quickbooks-online

I am unable to get a customer data in my Quickbooks Online Invoice sandbox account populated with complete shipping and billing address, primarily State and ZipCode.  Do any of the following "Line" properties correspond to Zip or State fields?  I can not get those to populate in my sandbox.

[image: Screenshot]

```
 var billaddr = addressRepository.Get(a => a.ContactMethodID == contactMethod.ContactMethodID && a.AddressTypeId == 2).First();
                var shipaddr = addressRepository.Get(a => a.ContactMethodID == contactMethod.ContactMethodID && a.AddressTypeId == 3).First();
                newCustomer.BillAddr = new PhysicalAddress() { City = billaddr.City, Line1 = billaddr.Address1, Line2 = billaddr.Address2, PostalCode = billaddr.ZipCode, Country = billaddr.Country, Line3 = billaddr.State, Line4 = billaddr.ZipCode };
                newCustomer.ShipAddr = new PhysicalAddress() { City = shipaddr.City, Line1 = shipaddr.Address1, Line2 = shipaddr.Address2, PostalCode = shipaddr.ZipCode, Country = shipaddr.Country, Line3 = shipaddr.State, Line4 = shipaddr.ZipCode };
```

https://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/html/3cbe37d6-2d4b-6811-fc81-54fe04ba2c3e.htm

```
Public property Line1   
    Product: QBW Description: First line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 41 characters. Product: QBO Description: First line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 500 characters.
    Public property Line2   
    Product: QBW Description: Second line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 41 characters. Product: QBO Description: Second line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 500 characters.
    Public property Line3   
    Product: QBW Description: Third line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 41 characters. Product: QBO Description: Third line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 500 characters.
    Public property Line4   
    Product: QBW Description: Fourth line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 41 characters. Product: QBO Description: Fourth line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 500 characters.
    Public property Line5   
    Product: QBW Description: Fifth line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 41 characters. Product: QBO Description: Fifth line of the address.[br /]Max. length: 500 characters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the link you provide to Intuit's documentation, it looks like State and Zip are encapsulated in the CountrySubDivisionCode and PostalCode properties of PhysicalAddress class, respectively:

```
CountrySubDivisionCode
Product: QBW 
Description: Region within a country. For example, state name for USA, province name for Canada.
Max. length: 21 characters. 
Product: QBO 
Description: Globalized representation of a region. For example, state name for USA, province name for Canada.
Max. length: 255 characters.

PostalCode
Product: QBW 
Description: Postal code. 
For example, zip code for USA and Canada.
Max. length: 13 characters. 
Product: QBO 
Description: Postal code. 
For example, zip code for USA and Canada.
Max. length: 30 characters.
```

I see you've tried PostalCode already; what are some examples of data you are attempting to assign to this property?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response!   Zip Example - 9000,   State - CA

Comment: @Vahe Sorry, I didn't get time yesterday to reply. I looked at the DLL in ILSPY to see if there was some validation in the PostalCode property (perhaps it required 5 character minimum, as an example) but didn't find any, so I'm not sure why it's not appearing.  Were you able to get the State to populate using CountrySubDivisionCode property?

Comment: No worries,  I made a mistake in my example, state should be 90000 for example.  It is 5 characters minimum.